# Click event on dynamically created link buttons not working

Tags: c#, asp.net

I want to give option to upload multiple files and then download it. I am creating link buttons Dynamically like:

```
 private void AddLinkButtons()
{
    string[] fileNames = (string[])Session["fileNames"];
    string[] fileUrls = (string[])Session["fileUrls"];
    if (fileNames != null)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < fileUrls.Length - 1; i++)
        {
            LinkButton lb = new LinkButton();

            phLinkButtons.Controls.Add(lb);
            lb.Text = fileNames[i];
            lb.CommandName = "url";
            lb.CommandArgument = fileUrls[i];
            lb.ID = "lbFile" + i;

            //lb.Click +=this.DownloadFile;
            lb.Attributes.Add("runat", "server");
            lb.Click += new EventHandler(this.DownloadFile);
            ////lb.Command += new CommandEventHandler(DownloadFile);

            phLinkButtons.Controls.Add(lb);
            phLinkButtons.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("<br>"));

        }
    }
```

And my DownloadFile event is:

```
protected void DownloadFile(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    LinkButton lb = (LinkButton)sender;
    string url = lb.CommandArgument;

    System.IO.FileInfo file = new System.IO.FileInfo(url);
    if (file.Exists)
    {
        try
        {
            Response.Clear();
            Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + file.Name);
            Response.AddHeader("Content-Length", file.Length.ToString());
            Response.ContentType = "application/octet-stream";
            Response.WriteFile(file.FullName);
            Response.End();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

        }
    }
    else
    {
        Response.Write("This file does not exist.");
    }
}
```

I am getting link buttons on screen but DownloadFile event is never called after clicking. i tried all options that are commented, but its not working. What is wrong in code?

Comment: Something wrong here? `LinkButton lb = new LinkButton(); lb = (LinkButton)lbTest;`

Comment: That was by mistake...I removed it, still not working.

Comment: phLinkButtons is placeholder in which I want to place link buttons

Comment: You by mistake wrote this line `phLinkButtons.Controls.Add(lb);` twice !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Where and when is AddLinkButtons() called ?

It should be called during init of your page, on each postback.

Depending on the logic of your page, your OnInit should look like this

```
    protected override void OnInit(EventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnInit(e);
        AddLinkButtons();

    }
```

Comment: @jbl..Thanks..This worked for me, I was not calling AddLinkButtons() on every postback..

Answer (score 1):

code seems fine ..

dont understand what is lbTest in AddLinkButtons() method.

please remove this line from AddLinkButtons() method.

```
lb = (LinkButton)lbTest;
```

Hope that will works...

Answer (score 0):

Add Link button after its properties have been set. Your Code is adding 2 lb buttons

```
        phLinkButtons.Controls.Add(lb); //------1
        lb.Text = fileNames[i];
        lb.CommandName = "url";
        lb.CommandArgument = fileUrls[i];
        lb.ID = "lbFile" + i;

        //lb.Click +=this.DownloadFile;
        lb.Attributes.Add("runat", "server");
        lb.Click += new EventHandler(this.DownloadFile);
        ////lb.Command += new CommandEventHandler(DownloadFile);

        phLinkButtons.Controls.Add(lb); //-------------------2
```

Remove First line